# How to use custom defined messages in another package?

Tags: catkin-make, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am new to ros and was writing code to publish and listen to a custom message. I am running ROS kinetic on Debian machine.

In my workspace I have two package - *aa* and *bb*. *aa* has a message `two_ints` as follows:

```
int16 a1
int16 b1
```

Both the packages use this message. When I catkin_make my workspace I get the following error in source of bb:

```
.../catkin_new/src/bb/src/src_bb.cpp:2:24: fatal error: aa/two_ints.h: No such file or directory
```

The CMakeLists.txt of aa is

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(aa)
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  roscpp
  std_msgs
  message_generation
)
add_message_files(
   FILES
   two_ints.msg
)
 generate_messages(
   DEPENDENCIES
   std_msgs
)
catkin_package(
  INCLUDE_DIRS include
  LIBRARIES aa
  CATKIN_DEPENDS roscpp std_msgs message_runtime
)
include_directories(
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)
add_executable(talker src/src_aa.cpp)
target_link_libraries(talker ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
add_dependencies(talker aa_generate_messages_cpp)
```

And CMakeLists.txt of bb is

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(bb)
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  roscpp
  std_msgs
)
catkin_package(
  INCLUDE_DIRS include
  LIBRARIES bb
  CATKIN_DEPENDS roscpp std_msgs
)
include_directories(
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)
add_executable(listener src/src_aa.cpp)
target_link_libraries(listener ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
add_dependencies(listener aa_generate_messages_cpp)
```

Directory structure is:

```
catkin_new
  -build
  -devel
  -src
     -CMakeLists.txt
     -aa
        -msg
           -two_ints.msg
        -include
        -src
           src_aa.cpp
        -...
     -bb
        -CMakeLists.txt
        -src
           -src_bb.cpp
        -...
```

Please help me out. I have tried various things but in vain. Also talker gets built even though it also includes aa/two_ints.h. Why so? And two_ints.h is present in devel/aa/ directory.

EDIT:
The aa/package.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package>
  <name>aa</name>
  <version>0.0.0</version>
  <description>The aa package</description>
  <license>TODO</license>
  <buildtool_depend>catkin</buildtool_depend>
  <build_depend>roscpp</build_depend>
  <build_depend>std_msgs</build_depend>
  <build_depend>message_generation</build_depend>
  <run_depend>roscpp</run_depend>
  <run_depend>std_msgs</run_depend>
  <run_depend>message_runtime</run_depend>
  </package>
```

The `bb/CMakeLists.txt' is modified and is as follows:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(bb)
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  roscpp
  std_msgs
  aa #changed here
)
catkin_package(
  INCLUDE_DIRS include
  LIBRARIES bb
  CATKIN_DEPENDS roscpp std_msgs aa #changed here
)
include_directories(
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)
add_executable(listener src/src_aa.cpp)
target_link_libraries(listener ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
add_dependencies(listener aa_generate_messages_cpp)
```

The 'bb/package.xml' is:

```
<package>
  <name>bb</name>
  <version>0.0.0</version>
  <description>The bb package</description>
  <buildtool_depend>catkin</buildtool_depend>
  <build_depend>roscpp</build_depend>
  <build_depend>std_msgs</build_depend>
  <build_depend>aa</build_depend>
  <run_depend>roscpp</run_depend>
  <run_depend>std_msgs</run_depend>
  <run_depend>aa</run_depend>
</package>
```

Now when I catkin_make the catkin_new workspace I get following error:

```
CMake Error at /home/mayank/Workspace/catkin_new/devel/share/aa/cmake/aaConfig.cmake:141 (message):
  Project 'bb' tried to find library 'aa'.  The library is neither a target
  nor built/installed properly.  Did you compile project 'aa'? Did you
  find_package() it before the subdirectory containing its code is included?
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:76 (find_package)
  bb/CMakeLists.txt:10 (find_package)
```

Looks like `bb` is getting built before/in parallel with `aa`. What am I missing?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/261641/how-to-use-custom-defined-messages-in-another-package?/) by [mayank](https://answers.ros.org/users/19704/mayank/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2017-05-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Does your `bb/package.xml` file exist? Do you depend on `aa`? In `bb/CMakeLists.txt` you do not have `aa` listed in `find_package()` or `catkin_pkg/CATKIN_DEPENDS`, which you will probably need.

---

Originally posted by [Thomas D](https://answers.ros.org/users/304/thomas-d/) with karma: 4347 on 2017-05-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-05-13**:
I've converted this to an answer, as it *is* the answer.

@mayank: catkin/cmake doesn't know that there is a build-time dependency (and thus a required ordering when building) without the information that @Thomas D writes about. Add `aa` to the `CATKIN_DEPENDS` of `bb` at least.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-05-13**:
See the [catkin howto](http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/catkin/html/howto/format2/index.html) documentation for more info on this.

**Comment by [mayank](https://answers.ros.org/users/19704/mayank/) on 2017-05-13**:
Yes, bb/package.xml exists and it contains 'aa' as build and run dependencies. Sorry forgot to include that in the question.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-05-13**:
Btw (from the `CMakeLists.txt` of `bb`):

> ```
> add_executable(listener src/src_aa.cpp)
> ```

```
...
add_dependencies(listener aa_generate_messages_cpp)
```

I'm assuming this is copy-pasta?

**Comment by [mayank](https://answers.ros.org/users/19704/mayank/) on 2017-05-13**:
I added the project `aa` in both the places in bb/CMakeLists.txt but it says: `Project 'bb' tried to find library 'aa'. The library is neither a target nor built/installed properly.  Did you compile project 'aa'? Did you find_package() it before the subdirectory containing its code is included?`

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-05-13**:
Please edit your question and **add** (do not overwrite) the updated `CMakeLists.txt` and `package.xml` for both packages.

**Comment by [mayank](https://answers.ros.org/users/19704/mayank/) on 2017-05-13**:
Yes @gvdhoorn it is mostly copy-paste.In fact this is my second project in ROS just after beginner-tutorials.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-05-13**:\

> ```
> LIBRARIES aa
> ```

I see this in the `CMakeLists.txt` of both `aa` and `bb`, but you never actually create any *libraries*, only *executables*. Please remove that from your `CMakeLists.txt`.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-05-13**:
Also: `bb` defines a `listener` target that tries to compile `src/src_aa.cpp`. I think that is a copy-paste mistake, correct?

And there is no need to `add_depencies(listener aa_generate_messages_cpp)` in `CmakeLists.txt` of `bb`. That will be handled automatically.

**Comment by [mayank](https://answers.ros.org/users/19704/mayank/) on 2017-05-13**:
Yup. Removing `LIBRARIES aa` and `LIBRARIES bb` from respective CMakeLists.txt solved this problem. And yes I corrected the `listener` target to depend on `src/src_bb.cpp`. Thanks a lot. It was really helpful. Also could you give me a linkto get through with the concept of Libraries and Executables.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-05-13**:
I wouldn't know of any ROS-specific documentation about that. This is really all CMake, not catkin. Know that catkin is really just a thin layer of convenience scripts/functionality over CMake.

**Comment by [mayank](https://answers.ros.org/users/19704/mayank/) on 2017-05-13**:
Okay. Thanks again. Gonna dig CMake then. Also should I mark this as correct as it only talks about  dependencies but not the wrong libraries.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-05-13**:
@Thomas D was basically correct: `CATKIN_DEPENDS` and `LIBRARIES` all have to do with dependencies: either those that are yours, or ones that you export as becoming dependencies of pkgs that use your package.